# vertical scroll inside HorizontalPager in Jetpack compose not working

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to add vertical scrolling inside HorizontalPager in Jetpack Compose.

Here is the code I am using

```
 HorizontalPager(
            count = showPagerEntries,
            state = pagerState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 12.dp, topEnd = 12.dp))
        ) { pageIndex ->

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .scrollable(
                        state = scrollState,
                        orientation = Orientation.Vertical
                    )
                    .height(506.dp)
                    .background(colorResource(id = R.color.white))
            ) {
              // other Jet pack compose elements like texts, images
            }
        }
```

The horizontal swiping of pages is working but the vertical scroll is not working.
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: use `LazyColumn` instead of `Column` inside `HorizontalPager`

Comment: use `Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())`

Answer (score 1):

**Try to add content inside a Box and provide the vertical scrolling to the Box. Then it will work fine with the Horizontal Pager.**

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
) {
    //Content here
}
```

**Your complete code will be like:**

```
HorizontalPager(
            count = showPagerEntries,
            state = pagerState,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 12.dp, topEnd = 12.dp))
        ) { pageIndex ->

            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .scrollable(
                        state = scrollState,
                        orientation = Orientation.Vertical
                    )
                    .height(506.dp)
                    .background(colorResource(id = R.color.white))
            ) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
               .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
) {
    //Content here like Text, Image etc
 }
```

}
}